# Transformar a base de dados no R - Uma espécie de tabela dinâmica

Tags: r

Possuo uma base de dados da seguinte forma:

```
CNPJ    SIGLA      chave            CENTRAL
3333    CREDSUL    CACHOEIRODIM-ES  CECOOPES
4444    COOPSEFES  VITORIA-ES       CECOOPES
55555   CREDI      VITORIA-ES       CECOOPES
66666   CREDEXTRA  SERRA-ES         CECOOPES
99999   ACENTRA    CRICIUMA-SC      CECRED
77777   ACREDICOOP JOINVILLE-SC     CECRED
11111   CREDCREA   FLORIANOPOLIS-SC CECRED
22222   CATARINA   FLORIANOPOLIS-SC CECRED
1010101 CREDELESC  FLORIANOPOLIS-SC CECRED
88888   CREDIFIESC FLORIANOPOLIS-SC CECRED
```

Gostaria de ter uma tabela final da seguinte forma:

```
chave            CNPJ1  SIGLA1    CENTRAL1  CNPJ2   SIGLA2  CENTRAL2    CNPJ3   SIGLA3  CENTRAL3    CNPJ4   SIGLA4  CENTRAL4
CACHOEIRODIM-ES  3333   CREDSUL   CECOOPES                                  
VITORIA-ES       4444   COOPSEFES CECOOPES  55555   CREDI-ALIMENTO  CECOOPES                        
SERRA-ES         66666  CREDEXTRA CECOOPES                                  
CRICIUMA-SC      99999  ACENTRA   CECRED                                    
JOINVILLE-SC     77777  ACREDICOOP CECRED                                   
FLORIANOPOLIS-SC 11111  CREDCREA  CECRED    22222   CATARINA CECRED 1010101 CREDELESC   CECRED   88888  CREDIFIESC CECRED
```

Tentei com o reshape mas não consegui bem o que queria.
É possível fazer isso de forma direta com algum pacote no R?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui fazer isso em duas etapa. Primeiro utilizado o *dplyr* para criar "SIGLAn" e "CENTRALn":

```
##Criando o contador
relcoop <- relcoop[order(relcoop$chave),] 
relcoopw<-relcoop %>% 
  group_by(chave) %>% 
  mutate(countercentral=paste0("CENTRAL",row_number()))

relcoopw<-relcoopw %>% 
  group_by(chave) %>% 
  mutate(countersigla=paste0("SIGLA",row_number()))
```

Em seguida transpus utilizando a função *spread* do pacote *tidyr*

```
##Tabela dinamica relcoop
library(tidyr)
relcoopwcentral<-spread(relcoopw,countercentral,CENTRAL)
relcoopwsigla<-spread(relcoopw,countersigla,SIGLA)
relcoopw<-cbind(relcoopwcentral,relcoopwsigla)
```